# Why does my tab bar break my AndEngine activity?

Tags: android, andengine

My Android app has a tab bar that uses an Intent to launch the content in each tab, as in Android's API Demos [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Tabs3.html). I've put an AndEngine activity under one of the tabs. My first question is: is this a reasonable idea? Or if I'm using AndEngine, is it better to implement my app's whole UI in AndEngine?

Assuming I'm not already onto a non-starter, the specific problem I've run up against is as follows. This AndEngine activity - the one I've incorporated in my tab-based app - is a simplified version of the AndEngine PinchZoom [example](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PinchZoomExample.java). It works well until you switch away from the tab and then back again. At that point, the view reappears, but you can't scroll or zoom any more.

Here's my activity class. Let me know if you want to see the tab bar class too. As you can see, I've tried to switch off the various listeners and detectors when the user leaves the tab, and switch them back on when they return. But I've established, using a breakpoint, that `onSceneTouchEvent` isn't called when I touch the screen after returning to the tab. Is something intervening and capturing my touch events? Or is there something that goes inactive and needs to be brought back to life?

I've also [posted](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/what-s-the-right-way-to-integrate-zoom-with-a-tab-bar-t6847.html) this question on the AndEngine forums.

**Edit:**

Thanks for your suggestions, Guillaume. You're right that `onResumeGame` isn't called when the user returns to the tab. I thought I'd checked that, but I must have confused myself by putting the scrollable graphic under two tabs at once. The `onResume` method is called at that point, while `onCreateGame` isn't. I've therefore changed the code so that the touch detectors are switched on in `onResume`. This method is definitely being called when I want it to be, so I guess that's progress, but `onSceneTouchEvent` still isn't being triggered when I touch the screen after returning to the tab. The updated code is below, with the changes marked as `// NEW`.

```
public class HomeActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener,
    IScrollDetectorListener, IPinchZoomDetectorListener {
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 628;

    private boolean mInitialised = false; // NEW
    private Scene mScene;
    private ZoomCamera mZoomCamera;
    private ITexture mTexture;
    private ITextureRegion mGrassTextureRegion;
    private SurfaceScrollDetector mScrollDetector;
    private PinchZoomDetector mPinchZoomDetector;
    private float mPinchZoomStartedCameraZoomFactor;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        this.mZoomCamera = new ZoomCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mZoomCamera);

        if (MultiTouch.isSupported(this)) {
            if (MultiTouch.isSupportedDistinct(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "MultiTouch detected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "MultiTouch detected, but your device has problems distinguishing between "
                        + "fingers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry your device does NOT support MultiTouch!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return engineOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources() {
        try {
            this.mTexture = new BitmapTexture() {
                @Override
                protected InputStream onGetInputStream() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/background_grass.png");
                }
            }.load(this.getTextureManager());
            this.mGrassTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mTexture);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setOnAreaTouchTraversalFrontToBack();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        // Calculate the coordinates for the sprite, so it's centered on the
        // camera.
        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mGrassTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mGrassTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

        // Create the sprite and add it to the scene.
        final Sprite grass = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mGrassTextureRegion,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        this.mScene.attachChild(grass);

        enableTouchDetectors(); // NEW
        mInitialised = true; // NEW

        return this.mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        this.mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(false);
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(null);
        this.mPinchZoomDetector = null;
        this.mScrollDetector = null;
        super.onPause();
    }

    // NEW method
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // If returning to the tab, switch the touch detectors back on.
        if (mInitialised) {
            enableTouchDetectors();
        }
    }

    // This method has been removed since Guillaume's answer.
//    @Override
//    public void onResumeGame() {
//        super.onResumeGame();
//        this.mScrollDetector = new SurfaceScrollDetector(this);
//        this.mPinchZoomDetector = new PinchZoomDetector(this);
//        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
//        this.mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStarted(final ScrollDetector pScollDetector, final int pPointerID,
        final float pDistanceX, final float pDistanceY) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(final ScrollDetector pScollDetector, final int pPointerID,
        final float pDistanceX, final float pDistanceY) {
        final float zoomFactor = this.mZoomCamera.getZoomFactor();
        this.mZoomCamera.offsetCenter(-pDistanceX / zoomFactor, -pDistanceY / zoomFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollFinished(final ScrollDetector pScollDetector, final int pPointerID,
        final float pDistanceX, final float pDistanceY) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPinchZoomStarted(final PinchZoomDetector pPinchZoomDetector,
        final TouchEvent pTouchEvent) {
        this.mPinchZoomStartedCameraZoomFactor = this.mZoomCamera.getZoomFactor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPinchZoom(final PinchZoomDetector pPinchZoomDetector,
        final TouchEvent pTouchEvent, final float pZoomFactor) {
        this.mZoomCamera.setZoomFactor(this.mPinchZoomStartedCameraZoomFactor * pZoomFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPinchZoomFinished(final PinchZoomDetector pPinchZoomDetector,
        final TouchEvent pTouchEvent, final float pZoomFactor) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        this.mPinchZoomDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);

        if (this.mPinchZoomDetector.isZooming()) {
            this.mScrollDetector.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                this.mScrollDetector.setEnabled(true);
            }
            this.mScrollDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // NEW method
    private void enableTouchDetectors() {
        this.mScrollDetector = new SurfaceScrollDetector(this);
        this.mPinchZoomDetector = new PinchZoomDetector(this);
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
        this.mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: On the first run of your code, enableTouchDetectors is called twice but does not need to be.

Comment: I've just checked in the debugger, and it's only called once. Perhaps your mistake was to assume that onResume is called after onCreateScene, when in fact it's called before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tommy:
I had this same scenario in my own app, in which I needed three tabs with one being andEngine. But i found that TabActivity did not re-initialize the tabs in the same way that firing a new Intent does. If you log the lifecycle of one of your other tabs, you will see this is not just an andengine thing, but a TabActivity thing.
There is a really useful thread here about the issue:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d89f1d5f913bb6f7

Including an example that sets each tab as views within a single activity.  here is the link. I've used code from commonsware myeslf and found their libraries and examples to be well tested and high-quality. 
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab/

In anycase, I could not find a way to make a tabactivity work without re-writing the core classes of Andengine, which was beyond the scope of what I could do in the project.

So what I did as a workaround was this: 
I build the tabs myself as three activities that shared a footer that lets you swap between them. I had to monkey around a bit with the history, and override the behavior of the back button to keep within the tabs when appropriate. 
Also, I used an intent flag in the Android manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Which helped the app run smoothly by assuring that there was only ever one instance of the Andengine tab ever created.

Hope this helps. It would be great if andengine could be made compatible with TabActivity, but I do not think it is fully at this moment.

Comment: Thanks very much. Bad news, but some promising leads. Unfortunately, I have some holiday coming up, so I may not be able to solve the issue before the bounty expires. What I'll do is award the bounty tomorrow evening if this still looks like the best answer, but wait to accept it until I've got a working solution.

Comment: Well i tried using a LayoutGameActivity for about an hour yesterday. It works fine as long as I don't add a tabhost. It compiles, it launches, but then it hangs. Never throws an error or anything. Just freezes.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for all your help. I'll award you the bounty now and then investigate properly when I get back from my trip.

Comment: Well thanks, I wish i could have found a solution. I tried again last night using the LayoutGameActivity, but again, there is somethign in the way Andengine inits itself that breaks with TabHost. If you find a solution post it here, please.

Comment: Have you updated your AndEngine library from the Git repository recently? I did that on Friday, and my problem seems to have magically disappeared!

Comment: GLES2. (Filler to make comment valid.)

Comment: Well, it's working now so I'm not going to investigate the problem with the older version of the library. I think your answer is very likely correct, so I'll accept it now.

Answer (score 2):

When you debug using breakpoint, is your `onResumeGame` method called?

Maybe you need to set your initialisations (specifically the `setOnSceneTouchListener(this)`) in a basic `onResume`? Or you could try adding it in `onCreateScene` too.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm a little further forward, but the problem remains. I've updated the question with details.